# Fingerprint of a Java WAR file

Tags: java, war

I'm writing a JAR library that can be included inside any WAR, sending log data to a server (*EDIT: it's an appender for Log4j*). In order to later group logs that originated from the same application version, but came from different servers, **I want to generate a fingerprint/checksum for the WAR**.

I thought about using classpath items and file sizes - but just can't seem to figure out the best way.

How would you do it?

Comment: The same WAR file might be deployed to 2 servers, I need an algorithm that throws out the same checksum/fingerprint for both running instances. It's not for versioning, it's just for distinguishing.

Comment: What about the built date from the MANIFEST.MF within the JAR? In difference to an hash it is more "human compatible".

Comment: I doubt you can do this; it all depends on the container; some explode the war before working with it, and run it all from a server.  Then how will you find the war?  It was built to be agnostic of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the only acceptable answer is: 
**it can't be done without irresponsible, nasty hacks.**

Answer (score 1):

You can find, with some variance for containers, the file location for the JAR within the WAR (maybe unzipped) like so:

AClassInTheJar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

Obviously that's a precursor to fingerprinting it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the **MD5 hash sum** out of the **WAR file** that is implemented in Java SE:

```
byte[] warBytes;
MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
digest.update(warBytes);
byte[] hash = digest.digest();
```

Refer to [Fast MD5 implementation](http://twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php) in Java and [Java SE API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html).

Comment: is a library within a WAR file allowed to do this?

Comment: I think the point of his question is finding the war file, from code.  The jar doesn't know where it is.

Comment: A Java program can, principally speaking, access any file on the file system with the appropriate rights (Unix) @Joeri That's of course a point, you somehow then need to initialize the jar or have a clever lookup through ClassLoader, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a cryptographic hash of the file is probably the most general solution.  And, in fact, if the file is signed the hash is already there, in the form of the signature.  (You don't need to "verify" the signature, just recognize that it's a "unique" identifier that might once or twice in the age of the universe not be truly unique.)

If the file isn't signed you can still (moderately) easily compute the hash using java.security.MessageDigest.

Comment: How would you locate the WAR file? I mean the library is running within it, how would it know "where it is"?

Comment: Good question.  I'm not real familiar with how WAR files are handled (and it may be that it varies a lot depending on what platform is using them).  I know you can generally locate the JAR file containing a class by looking at the class's class loader and then querying that class loader for its search path, but I don't know if that general concept carries over to WAR files or not.